# Mac terminal login via SSH key without entering password.

Tags: ssh, mac, terminal

I am trying to log into SSH using the terminal:

```
ssh root@example.com -p54 -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key
```

Custom port number 45.
Chmod 600 ssh_key.

I know that the SSH key works correctly because I can connect fine via Putty on windows. What could be the problem?

Comment: add `-vv` to your ssh command line and reconnect.  Paste the verbose output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generated the key in Windows using PuTTYgen and copied the key straight over to your linux workstation, it's likely the key is in the wrong format. You should be able to use PuTTYgen to convert the key into the standard OpenSSH format.

As an aside, best practice is to have a unique keypair for each device you connect from. Just generate a new keypair on the linux workstation and add that public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `example.com`.

Comment: Exporting direct through putty worked perfect thanks.

Comment: Good. You really ought to generate a unique keypair for the mac, though.